# searching in arraylist always not found

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, arraylist

no matter what I use indexof() or contains or .equals() changing everything to uppercase or to lowercase It always return false and not found can someone please tell me what is going on?

```
class Students{
    private ArrayList<String> snames;
    private String tname;
//this one combines both question 2 and 4.    
public Students(String tname){
    
snames=new ArrayList<>();
this.tname=tname;
    

}    
    
    
public String gettname(){return tname;}
public ArrayList<String> getsnames(){return snames;}

public void addStudent(String name){
    snames.add(name);
    
    
    
    
}

    
public boolean studentExists(String name){

boolean e=false;
for(String i:snames){
if(i.contains(name)){
    
    e=true;

}   
}
return e;    
}    
    
    
    
}
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

Scanner k=new Scanner(System.in);
out.println("what is your name?");
String name=k.nextLine();
out.println(name.toUpperCase());
Students s=new Students(name);
out.println("enter student name");
String snames=k.nextLine();
while(snames!="."){
     out.println("enter student name");
snames=k.nextLine();    
s.addStudent(snames);    
if (snames.equals("."))    
break;
}       
out.println("who u want to find");
String target=k.nextLine();

boolean exist=s.studentExists(target);

if(exist==true){
out.println("Found student");
}
else out.println("Student not found.");
out.println(exist);     
}
    

    
    
}
```

no matter what I use indexof() or contains or .equals() changing everything to uppercase or to lowercase It always return false and not found can someone please tell me what is going on?

Comment: It seems to work for me, make sure the case is matching.  Was your intention to do a imprecise match (`String#contains`) as apposed to a precise match (`String#equals`).  You might like to share you input data as well

Comment: actually I get it now I never put s.addStudent(snames); before the while loop so the first input will not be saved thank you for clearing this

Comment: But you don't "need" to work that way, and you probably shouldn't, because then you'd be doing `if (!".".equals(name)) {...}` all over the place.  Work to reduce code duplication

Answer (score 1):

You have a logic issue...

```
out.println("enter student name");
String snames = k.nextLine();
while (snames != ".") {
    out.println("enter student name");
    snames = k.nextLine();
    s.addStudent(snames);
    if (snames.equals(".")) {
        break;
    }
}
```

You...

1. Prompt for the name
2. Read the next line of input
3. Check to see if it's the exit condition (by the way, `snames != "."` is wrong, it should be `!".".equals(snames)`
4. You prompt them to enter the name
5. You read the input
6. You write the input to `Students`
7. You check for the exit condition ... again

So, between 3 and 4, you never write what was first entered by the user, so, if you only enter

```
enter student name
jack
enter student name
.
```

Only `.` will be added to the list

Instead, you should be doing something more like...

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
Students students = new Students("Test");

String name = ".";
do {
    System.out.print("enter student name (or \".\" to exit) ");
    name = scanner.nextLine();
    if (!name.equals(".")) {
        students.addStudent(name);
    }
} while (!name.equals("."));

do {
    System.out.print("who u want to find (or \".\" to exit) ");
    name = scanner.nextLine();
    if (!name.equals(".")) {
        if (students.studentExists(name)) {
            System.out.println("Match found");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Match not found");
        }
    }
} while (!name.equals("."));
```

The important point here is to make sure when you ask for input, you are actually writing it the list, unless it's the exit value (ie `.`)

Answer (score 1):

The code is bad-structured, and the first `snames` is never added to the `ArrayList`.

See the codes below in class `Main`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
    // ignore the teacher name part
    Students s = new Students(name);
    // when the first snames is received,
    System.out.println("enter student name");
    String snames = k.nextLine();
    while (snames != ".") {
        // the name is not saved, but another snames is received.
        System.out.println("enter student name");
        snames = k.nextLine();
        System.out.println(snames);
        s.addStudent(snames);
        // the "." is also saved as well.
        if (snames.equals("."))
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I would suggest modifying the `while` loop into something like this:

```
    Students student = new Students(tname);
    // no need to get scanner output before loop
    String sname;
    do {
        System.out.println("enter student name");
        sname = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println(sname);
        student.addStudent(sname);
    } while (!sname.equals("."));
```

Hope this answer helps you well.